# metaio in iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, camera, metaio

I've developed an iOS app that recognizes some logos. The metaio SDK runs fine in iPad Mini, iPhone 5 and iPhone 4S.

In iPhone 4 the SDK runs really slow and sloppy. How can I fix this?

Btw, I'm using the latest SDK and iOS 7 in every device.

Thanks.

Comment: thats the slower device performance of the old ip4. dont think that you can do anything.

Comment: I downloaded the iWorld app from the store and it has a setting named "toggle cam drawing" which enables the iPhone 4 camera to run normally. So there is something I can do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed it with the following:**

```
[glView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
m_metaioSDK->setSeeThrough(true);
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer = m_metaioSDK->getCameraPreviewLayer();
previewLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

**The documentation:**
Get a camera preview layer from the active camera session.
Use this to get a pointer to a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer that is created based on the current camera session. You can use this to draw the camera image in the background and add a transparent EAGLView on top of this. To prevent sdk from drawing the background in OpenGL you can activate the see-through mode.

**Answer from the metaio guys:**
The 'toggle cam drawing' just sets the background of the renderer transparent and puts the native camera preview in the background. just have a look at the documentation of

virtual AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* getCameraPreviewLayer()
This provides the illusion that everything is running faster. However, the tracking speed will still be slow. In case of a pure-detection scenario, this might be fine. In case you want to overlay, it will result in a swimming augmentation.

Better would be for you to have a look why it's running slow in the first place. If you have many targets in your tracking-configuration, you could set the MaxObjectsToDetectPerFrame parameter to only look for a few patterns per frame. ( http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tracking-config/optical-tracking/image-tracking/)